# VisionOS window 3d position and rotation

Tags: swiftui, window, visionos

I am playing with vision OS on simulator, and trying to make a virtual keyboard similar to the standard one (but with different buttons). I can make another WindowGroup in my app and fill it with buttons, and open it when app needs input.

However, I want this keyboard window to appear on similar position as the standard keyboard do (below main window), and in similar 3d rotation (as if "lying on the table", but not based on some physical object). How can I specify the position of newly opened window and its 3d rotation?

I expected there will be WindowGroup modifiers for that, but I can't find any.

Comment: Similar question here. Relevant [docs are here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/positioning-and-sizing-windows), and it recommends using `WindowGroup.defaultPosition`, but I get an error `'defaultPosition' is unavailable in visionOS` in Xcode 15 beta 8.

Comment: Docs mention this: `In visionOS, the system places new windows directly in front of people, where they happen to be gazing at the moment the window opens. This helps to ensure that people become aware of newly opened windows.` For your keyboard, you may be better off with a Volume instead of a WindowGroup.